# XCTest gets stuck when i run pressForDuration:0 thenDragToCoordinate

Tags: objective-c, xctest

I am trying to scroll from one point to other point in XCTest with below code but my app and execution hangs whenever I run this code ,can anyone guide me out

```
XCUICoordinate* Start = [[app coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0, 0)] coordinateWithOffset:CGVectorMake(375,667)];
NSLog(@"Start ====== %@ ",Start);
XCUICoordinate* Finish = [[app coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0,64)] coordinateWithOffset:CGVectorMake(375,603)];
NSLog(@"Finish ====== %@ ",Finish);
[Start pressForDuration:0 thenDragToCoordinate:Finish];
```

and also tried

```
XCUICoordinate* Start = [app coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];
NSLog(@"Start ====== %@ ",Start);
XCUICoordinate* Finish = [app coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0,64)];
NSLog(@"Finish ====== %@ ",Finish);
[Start pressForDuration:0 thenDragToCoordinate:Finish];
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: Try it with 0 instead of 64 when getting the finish coordinate with normalised offset. Using 64 will be trying to find the point that is 64 times the screen height below the current screen. Surprised this doesn't crash instead of hang. Is there any error message?

Comment: is this not x and y co-ordinates ?

Comment: Nope :) it's for creating a vector with sizes relative to the element

Comment: Is there any document which can explain me what this does exactly, because I thought this x and y co-ordinates. I tried apple documents but it is of not much use